# If a correct answer to a question is edited, should / does the questioner get informed?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, notifications

So a question has various answers and the question asker marks the best one for their situation as correct, we all know how that work and it's pretty basic.

My question is this:

> If a question asker marks a question as answered then when that answer is updated (either by the original poster or another editor), do they - or if not, *should they* - be informed that the answer they have marked as the correct one for their situation has been changed?

Unfortunately I can't find any existing knowledge on this and my own experience is blank on this front, is this something that is currently in place and if not would it be useful to have to at least give question askers chance to review that the correct answers marked as such can be appropriately reviewed by the question asker?

*Extra info*

I semi-often see on review posts qustions that have been marked as correct being updated by someone who is not the question answerer, with the premise that (for older questions/answers) technology has moved on and the new editor is trying to keep the answers up to date with the current standard (I think I often decline thes edits, but that's not the point, as above 2.5K review is not needed for editing other posts).

Comment: Unless it has changed recently, I don't believe the asker is automatically notified of edits to any answers, even the accepted one. I'm pretty sure I've seen it mentioned in a meta post somewhere...

Comment: Do you think that there is a potential for this to be added in the future, or as a topic worth exploring more? I think as well as in general, in specific cases where Q&A are years old and then someone (typically with a couple thousand rep) edits the answer adding new details about new versions of the subject software which potentially makes the answer less applicable to the original question. (I see this mostly with Javascript)

Comment: I'm sure it's been brought up before. I could kinda see the benefit of notifying the asker if the accepted answer has been edited, but I could also see it as just being annoying if the edits aren't anything important. If I ever edit an accepted answer with something notable, I just ping the asker to let them know. I assume that's probably the generally agreed-upon method, since, AFAIK, that's how it's always been.